# Allocate memory for a dynamic string of char

Tags: c

I am trying to make a function that will allocate memory dynamically while the user hit any key other than ENTER. The code compiles without errors or warnings (on gcc) but is not working properly...could someone tell me what is going wrong exactly?

I got the code to work if I modify the function to return a pointer to char i,e, something like

`char * getString(char * string);`

However I am still curious about the original code and why is not working, would very much appreciate any explanation. Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to read this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getString(char * string);

int main(void){

    char * str = NULL;

    printf("Write something:\n");
    getString(str);
    printf("You wrote:\n");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);

    return 0;
}


void getString(char * string){
    char ch;
    int length = 0;

    do{
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        if(length == 0){
            string = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
        } else {
            string = (char *) realloc(string, (length + 1) * sizeof(char));
        }
        if(string == NULL){
            printf("ERROR: memory could not be allocated!!\n");
        }

        string[length] = ch;
        length++;
    } while(ch != '\n');

    string[length - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Changing `string` inside `getString(char * string)` does not affect calling code's `str`.

Answer (score 5):

The `string` parameter is being passed in to `getString()` *by value*, so it is a *copy* of the `str` variable, and as such any changes that `getString()` makes to `string` itself, like assigning a memory address to it, are not reflected in the original `str` variable.

To fix this, you need to pass the `string` parameter *by pointer* instead.

You also need to fix the memory leak and access violation that your code has if `realloc()` fails.

Try this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getString(char ** string);

int main(void){

    char * str = NULL;

    printf("Write something:\n");
    getString(&str);
    printf("You wrote:\n");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}

void getString(char ** string){
    char ch, *newstr;
    int length = 0;

    if (string == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: invalid parameter!!\n");
        return;
    }
    *string = NULL;

    do{
        if (scanf("%c", &ch) < 1) {
            ch = '\n';
        }

        newstr = (char *) realloc(*string, length + 1);
        if (newstr == NULL){
            printf("ERROR: memory could not be allocated!!\n");
            free(*string);
            *string = NULL;
            return;
        }
        *string = newstr;

        newstr[length] = ch;
        length++;
    }
    while (ch != '\n');

    (*string)[length - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: sizeof(char) is by definition 1. Do not cast the result of malloc

Comment: `(*string)[length] = '\0';` is out of bounds access to the allocated space. Casting the return value of `realloc` is pointless.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I fixed the bounds error. As for the type cast, it is not necessary in C and is harmless, but if this code is ever compiled as-is in C++ then the cast is required (of course, C++ has much better ways to approach this issue)

Comment: The question doesn't contain `c++` tag. And It is beyond me why one would want to compile C code with a C++ compiler. Also, this code may cause infinite loop if EOF condition occurs before reading newline character.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin "*The question doesn't contain `c++` tag*" - I know, but who knows how this code could end up being used in the future, by the OP or someone else. But whatever. I removed the cast and `sizeof` now. "*And It is beyond me why one would want to compile C code with a C++ compiler*" - it happens all the time, especially C-based libraries. A lot of open source code is C. "*Also, this code may cause infinite loop if EOF condition occurs before reading newline character*" - fixed.

Comment: I'm *not* talking about *linking* a C based library to a C++ project. I'm talking about *compiling* the C code with a C++ compiler. The incompatibilities between the two languages may bite.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin "*I'm not talking about linking a C based library to a C++ project. I'm talking about compiling the C code with a C++ compiler*" - so was I. I've *compiled* plenty of C library sources into my C++ projects over the years.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to implement your solution.
You should use double pointer as the argument of `getString` which is going to store the input string from the user.

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void getString(char**); // function prototype

/* Main function */
int main()
{
    /* Pointer to point to the memory location
     * where input string will be stored */
    char *s=NULL;
    /* Call by reference,the function will place 
     * string in memory location where the pointer
     *  is pointing */
    getString(&s); 
    printf("s=%s\n",s);
    
    free(s);
    return 0;
}

/* getString function will
 * store each input character in
 * the allocated memory area. */
void getString(char** p)
{
    if(*p==NULL){
        if((*p=malloc(1*sizeof(char)))==NULL)
            exit(0);
    }

    int c; //Variable to store each input character
    size_t i=0; //Counter to keep track of the size of the input string

    while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF){
        char* newp = realloc(*p,i+1);
        if(newp==NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"realloc failed\n");
            free(p);
            exit(0);
        }
        *p = newp;
        *(*p+i)=c;
        i++;
    }
    *(*p+i)='\0'; //Null character to end the string.
}
```

Comment: wrong use of realloc (if malloc fails memory leak) and malloc (no result check)

Comment: I think enough issues for DV

Comment: still not correct realloc. Still cast of the malloc & realloc. Sizeof not needed as sizeof(char) is by definition 1

Comment: because it silences potential warning. void * can be converted to any pointer without the cast.

Comment: An this code still has a potential UB is realloc fails

Comment: exit after realloc will cause memory leak. It is not any better/